# Is there a specific way to call a function within another function?

Tags: haskell

I am setting up a recursive function which calls another function to shift the values from one string to another. I have everything working within function `left`, but i am struggling understanding the syntax on how to call the `left` function recursively.

The function should stop when it detects white space (`" "`) in value `a`.

```
left :: (String, String) -> (String, String) 
left (a, b) = (reverse(tail(reverse a)), ((head(reverse a))) :b)

reu' :: (String, String) -> (String, String)
reu' (a, b)
    | a ==  " " = (a, b)
    reu'(a, b) = left (a, b)
```

Input: `"This is an ex""ample of a string"`

Expected: `"This is an""example of a string"`

Comment: do you mean, for the last line, `| otherwise = reu' (left (a, b))`?

Comment: The stopping condition isn't when `a` *equals* a string with a single space; it's when `a` *ends* with a space.

Comment: PS you can simplify this code at least a bit: `reverse(tail(reverse a))` is simply `init a`. (And even if you insist on chaining 3 functions, it would be more idiomatic to write it as `(reverse . tail . reverse) a`)

Comment: The line `reu'(a, b) = left (a, b)` has the wrong indentation, it should start in the same column as the `reu' ...` a few lines above.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, helped a lot.

Comment: did you mean the expected result of `("This is an " , "example of a string")`, `("This is an" , " example of a string")`, or really the `("This is an" , "example of a string")`?

Comment: To add onto robins comment, most of these basic functions on list exist already, you can find them with a quick search on https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to analyze the *end* of `a`, the recursion will get a little hairy. I might use the pre-defined `init` and `last` functions to make this easier, and work with words, not individual characters. Note, this will replace the need for `left`.

```
reu' (String, String) -> (String, String)
reu' a b = let w = words a  -- ["This", "is", "an", "ex"]
               a' = init w  -- ["This", "is", "an']
           in (unwords a', last w : b)
```

If you want to do the recursion yourself, it's simpler to reverse `a` *once*, and move characters from the *front* of that string to the front of `b`, then re-reverse what's left once you find the space.

```
reu' (String, String) -> (String, String)
reu' a b = reu'' (reverse a) b  -- reu'' "xe si na sihT" "ample of a string"
     where reu'' "" ys = ("", ys)
           reu'' (' ':xs) ys = (reverse xs, ys)
           reu'' (x:xs) ys = reu'' xs (x:ys)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Can you give me any reason why my question was down voted? I thought it was pretty well structured.